# Crash when waiting for WorkerThread in Destructor

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2009, virtualtreeview

I have a problem with Virtual Treeview Destructor, which stops the WorkerThread while it is still running.

Code:

```
destructor TBaseVirtualTree.Destroy;
begin
  Exclude(FOptions.FMiscOptions, toReadOnly);
  ReleaseThreadReference(Self);
```

and the code for ReleaseThreadReference:

```
procedure ReleaseThreadReference(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree);
begin
  if Assigned(WorkerThread) then
  begin
    Dec(WorkerThread.FRefCount);

    // Make sure there is no reference remaining to the releasing tree.
    Tree.InterruptValidation;

    if WorkerThread.FRefCount = 0 then
    begin
      with WorkerThread do
      begin
        Terminate;
        SetEvent(WorkEvent);
      end;
      FreeAndNil(WorkerThread);
      CloseHandle(WorkEvent);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And output from WinDbg:

```
FAULTING_IP: 
vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+3
501f0b57 807b0800        cmp     byte ptr [ebx+8],0

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 501f0b57 (vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+0x00000003)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000000
   Parameter[1]: 00000008
Attempt to read from address 00000008

PROCESS_NAME:  MyProcess.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000008

READ_ADDRESS:  00000008 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+0
501f0b54 53              push    ebx

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000894

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set via attribute from Frame 0 on thread 894

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_WINDOW_HOOK

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 501c565d to 501f0b57
00d7eca4 501c565d 00d7efb0 028408b9 00d7ee74 vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+0x3
00d7edd0 501c9cec 00d7ee74 01a58e10 77c2c3ce vcl120!Controls.TControl.WndProc+0x2d5
00d7ee10 501e5a59 00d7efb0 028408b9 02190e80 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.WndProc+0x518
00d7ee3c 501c9403 00d7ee50 50007cb0 00d7ee6c vcl120!Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc+0x599
00d7ee6c 500591de 00000046 00000000 00d7efb0 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc+0x2f
00d7ee84 77d48709 002b00ee 00000046 00000000 rtl120!Classes.StdWndProc+0x16
00d7eeb0 77d4d297 028408b9 002b00ee 00000046 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
00d7ef18 77d4b368 00000000 028408b9 002b00ee user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0xea
00d7ef6c 77d4d1da 01c9c880 00000046 00000000 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa3
00d7ef94 7c90eae3 00d7efa4 00000030 01c9c880 user32!__fnINOUTLPWINDOWPOS+0x27
00d7efac 002b00ee 00000000 00000000 00000000 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x13
00d7efe8 501e6a2b 002b00ee 00000000 00d7f1cc MainControls!TUJournalIntf.ImportFunFile+0x33a
00d7f020 501e88cc 02190e80 00d7f158 501c565d vcl120!Forms.TCustomForm.SetMenu+0x197
00d7f02c 501c565d 00d7f35c 028408b9 00d7f1fc vcl120!Forms.TCustomForm.WMNCCreate+0x20
00d7f158 501c9cec 00d7f1fc 00d7f1a4 501c9cec vcl120!Controls.TControl.WndProc+0x2d5
00d7f198 501e5a59 00d7f35c 028408b9 02190e80 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.WndProc+0x518
00d7f1c4 501c9403 00d7f1d8 501c941b 00d7f1f4 vcl120!Forms.TCustomForm.WndProc+0x599
00d7f1f4 500591de 00000081 00000000 00d7f35c vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc+0x2f
00d7f20c 77d48709 002b00ee 00000081 00000000 rtl120!Classes.StdWndProc+0x16
00d7f238 77d4d297 028408b9 002b00ee 00000081 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
00d7f2a0 77d4b368 00000000 028408b9 002b00ee user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0xea
00d7f2f4 77d4e840 01c9c880 00000081 00000000 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa3
00d7f324 7c90eae3 00d7f334 00000060 00000060 user32!__fnINLPCREATESTRUCT+0x8b
00d7f390 77d517eb 77d517b1 00050000 00d7f8b8 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x13
00d7f834 77d518a4 00050000 00d7f8b8 00d7f8cc user32!NtUserCreateWindowEx+0xc
00d7f8e0 77d51b08 00050000 00d7fa04 00d7f8cc user32!_CreateWindowEx+0x1ed
00d7f91c 50122dd0 00050000 00d7fa04 0b3413bc user32!CreateWindowExW+0x33
00d7f964 501c8b29 00000000 50120000 00000000 vcl120!Windows.CreateWindowEx+0x44
00d7faa8 501c8a47 00d7fc80 501c8ae7 00d7fbc4 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.CreateWindowHandle+0x35
00d7fbc4 501e3682 02190e80 501e7787 00d7f9cc vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.CreateWnd+0x13f
00d7fc18 77d4d86f 000100a8 00d7fc68 00d7fcf8 vcl120!Forms.TScrollingWinControl.CreateWnd+0xa
00d7fc38 77d4d94b 00000000 00000000 501ed470 user32!InternalEnumWindows+0x5a
00d7fc58 501ed556 501ed470 00d7fc68 00450242 user32!EnumWindows+0x16
00d7fce0 500591de 0000001c 00000000 00000454 vcl120!Forms.TApplication.DoNormalizeTopMosts+0x32
00d7fcf8 77d48709 00450242 0000001c 00000000 rtl120!Classes.StdWndProc+0x16
00d7fd24 77d487eb 02840fe2 00450242 0000001c user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
00d7fd8c 77d4b368 00000000 02840fe2 00450242 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
00d7fde0 77d4b3b4 01c8f058 0000001c 00000000 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa3
00d7fe08 7c90eae3 00d7fe18 00000018 01c8f058 user32!__fnDWORD+0x24
00d7fe2c 77d493c6 77d49385 00d7feac 00000000 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x13
00d7fe58 77d493df 00d7feac 00000000 00000000 user32!NtUserPeekMessage+0xc
00d7fe84 500576a4 00d7feac 00000000 00000000 user32!PeekMessageW+0xbc
00d7fee8 50006c37 5002b6a9 01783c94 00d7ff08 rtl120!Classes.TThread.WaitFor+0x5c
00d7fef8 0178fc99 00000003 021d5800 021d5830 rtl120!System.TObject.Free+0xb
00d7ff08 501c7240 02190e80 021d5830 021d5830 VirtualTreesR!VirtualTrees.TBaseVirtualTree.Destroy+0x21
00d7ff1c 501cef46 00000002 00000000 501c7240 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.Destroy+0x90
00d7ff28 501c7240 00d7ff64 02190e80 02190e80 vcl120!Controls.TCustomControl.Destroy+0x22
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 vcl120!Controls.TWinControl.Destroy+0x90

SYMBOL_NAME:  vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+0

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: vcl120

IMAGE_NAME:  vcl120.bpl

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a0b8b7f

STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; ~~[894] ; .frame 0 ; ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_c0000005_vcl120.bpl!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_CLASS_PTR_DEREFERENCE_WINDOW_HOOK_vcl120!Forms.TGlassFrame.FrameExtended+0
```

If you look at this line in callstack "0000001c 00000000 rtl120!Classes.StdWndProc+0x16", you can see that application processed WM_ACTIVATEAPP(0x1C) message and called "DoNormalizeTopMosts" (I think this leads to create main form again). I found in our project DevExpress6 with "dxBarWndProcHook", maybe this is a problem, but I'm not sure. I have no idea why this is happen - function TThread.WaitFor processed message which leads to recreate form.

Please, could anyone help me to solve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure the exception comes from there ? Could you provide an SSCCE ?

Comment: Problem is surely in your code, which you did not show.

Comment: Thank you for answers. The project is huge and I can't post all the source code.. MyVT of type "TVirtualStringTree" is design component, in FormDestroy it is called MyVT.Clear(). It seems that the problem is in destructor of MyVT (TBaseVirtualTree.Destroy) when waiting for WorkerThread to stop (WorkerThread is a global of Virtual TreeView component). Please, could you tell me is it OK to call FreeAndNil(WorkerThread) which leads to WorkerThread.WaitFor in destructor of TBaseVirtualTree?? And please, could you explain the callstack from PeekMessageW+0xbc (7th line from bottom)? Thank you!

Comment: Nobody wants all of your code. We just want an SSCCE.

Comment: I see. But the file with VT has thousands lines and make a short compilable example can take a lot of time and I think it is useless.. because I have never reproduced this crash - I've got only reports (dumps) from customers. I understand that you can't help me without having source code..

Comment: Which version of VirtualTreeView have you been using? Why do you call MyVT.Clear()? Of course the tree will be cleared before it is destroyed. How exactly do you know that the exception comes from this code?

Comment: Without a repro it's going to be hard I agree. Have you tried with full debug FastMM. This can turn intermittent AVs into every time repros.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answers, I'm using FastMM with full debug mode but without success.
I found out that this is not a problem in VT, because I have another crash reported without VT in callstack (but it was the same situation - waiting for worker thread in Destructor).
If you look at this line in callstack "0000001c 00000000 rtl120!Classes.StdWndProc+0x16", you can see that application processed WM_ACTIVATEAPP(0x1C) message and called "DoNormalizeTopMosts" (I think this leads to create main form again). I found in our project DevExpress6 with "dxBarWndProcHook", maybe this is a problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm 99% sure, that this is a bug in Delphi.. you can look here: http://www.bergsoft.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=3538 and here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=64729

Comment: Maybe I found a workaround: to call "Hide" and "Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False" in FormDestroy of mainForm. Because if MainFormOnTaskBar is False, function NormalizeTopMosts doesn't produce creation of mainForm again (if not exists).